# Auto app-resize for Iphone 6 Plus only (i.e. not Iphone 6)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

My problem is that I have skipped support for the Iphone 6P screen size due to time constraints. In other words, the app that is to be released will work on Iphone 4-6, but not 6P. What I want is either to not release the app for Iphone 6P (is that possible?) or, in the best case, make the autoresizing work for Iphone 6P like it did before I added the launchscreen for Iphone 6 (note: no launchscreen for iphone 6P).

**tl;dr:**
How do I make the auto appresizing work for Iphone 6P but not Iphone 6? Alternatively, if that is not possible, how do I skip support for Iphone 6P altogether, i.e. so that it does not appear in App Store for those devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'm afraid it can't be done. As long as you support iPhone 6 you have to support iPhone 6+. And you cannot tell the app to resize just for the 6+.

I'm sorry, you'll have to work all night long. :) But with autolayout and size classes, it can be achieved quite easily: https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/

Comment: Well, if you have pixel perfect design like I do, then it's not just a matter of one night... Adaptation to Iphone 6 took 50 hours or more. Are you sure about your answer? I mean, did Apple say that you either support both 6 and 6P, or none at all? How do you know?

Comment: Sorry to hear about your pixel perfect design. I'm sure of my answer because the only way to have your app resized for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6Plus is to use older SDKs. And as long as you use iOS 8+ SDK (compulsory for iPhone 6) you *MUST* be iPhone6+ aware.

Comment: But how come the resizing starts to work if I clear the launch images for both 6 and 6P? I do not change the SDK...

Comment: Indeed, and it's because it's exactly the same process for the 4" screen compatibility back in the iPhone 5 release. When you put the 4" launch screen, it allowed the full resolution. When it was not here, your app was only compatible with 3.5" screens. This is the same logic here. When you have a launch image you have the adaptive screen sizes opt-in. But the real problem, is that you **CANNOT** distinguish the zoom process between iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+. By the way, have you tried your pixel perfect design using the Display Zoom on the iPhone 6? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203073

Comment: Ok, lacking any other options, I will have to trust you. In fact, I have already started the adaptation. Regarding the display zoom feature: no, I didn't actually test it until you asked me about it. It looks ok, but I guess it should do so by default as there is no option to provide app icons for this case, and those icons are pixel perfect too.

Comment: Well good luck then. And as soon as your app is released, let me know, I'd like to view it on my 6+!

Comment: Oh, I see you're biased. :) Sure, I will let you know! Thanks!

Comment: Damn! I'm in a tight spot! ;o)

Comment: It's released now. :) Search for "Money Left" (it's the one with the green bar and the coin stack) on app store or visit this link: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/money-left/id992834826?ls=1&mt=8

Comment: Great! I've seen you do not have French translation yet. Would you need some help?

Comment: Yes, I will need some help with that as soon as I see that the app is giving enough revenue. You can contact me at lukas@appkopk.com.